# When I hold a stepper motor while it is operating, what happens? Does it draw more current or maybe reverse current?

Tags: current, stepper-motor, calibration

I was wondering how stepper motors of 3D printers work and I found that some of them does not have a calibrating mechanism like a switch or whatsoever. It seems like there is an internal thing that is causing the calibration of the stepper motors. I am trying to see if it is possible to find when a stepper motor is on one end and cant rotate anymore where it is still while it was operating due to that it cant hold enough torque to overcome the exerted force (imagine holding it with your hand while it is operating and stopping it. Could someone explain what happens at this scenario. Thank you!

Comment: What you need is a limit switch. Or encoder. Or both. When your stepper is stuck, a lot of things are happening, and many can be detected, but people don't usually do it. Besides, you don't want your motor to slip, because it's hard to do anything about it.

Comment: https://dynomotion.com/Help/Russian/ClosedLoopStep/ClosedLoopStepper.html?id=1&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAopuvBhBCEiwAm8jaMTGfJInQmqOqwLw-FBi06euelTLK0P6Gvwhkm8Hw1BNhsQi3vj3rwBoC08cQAvD_BwE

Comment: Think of a bunch of people lined up passing buckets.  Each one needs to be ready to accept a bucket when one passes it.  If one isn't, maybe the bucket carrier turns around with it and returns to sender. What happens when the bucket freezes midway when a third person interferes with the handoff by grabbing the bucket mid pass and holding it there?

Comment: I suppose running it up against a mechanical end stop (running it long enough that it will hit the stop no matter from where it started) would be a crude and noisy way of homing but it wouldn't be very nice on the mechanism and could cause jams. Some mass-produced  systems  using low-torque steppers do use this method, but a 3D printer is not really a low-torque application.